# Rash on face, what is the most likely cause and best treatment?

Tags: topical-cream-gel, rash, eczema, face

Okay, I've got a Rash on my face. It's red and blotchy like broken capillaries but smooth to the touch. It doesn't hurt and is not itchy. The closest condition I can describe it to is Rosacea, but not experiencing half the symptoms of it so I cannot be too sure that is the diagnosis. Could be related to eczema - have had this before in the past on arms.

It's on my Cheeks and a tiny bit on my chin.

It seems to become inflamed after I wash my face.

If I had to compare how it looks I would say it is [very similar to this](http://www.commonskinconditions.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/capillary-repair.jpg).

I've had it for years and am exhausting options. Have seeked professional advice with no avail, now looking here for help.

Many thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't really say over the internet what it is with certainty nor can we offer a solution. The only thing we can recommend is that you be persistent in asking for a solution from medical professionals in person - if one can't help, try looking for a second (or third) opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the help lucky, unfortunately all the professional advice I've seeked out have come back as uncertain also. Each have provided a solution very different from the last. Since this is the case, I would prefer to take the routes with as little side effects as possible first before going to the more extreme options. So far I have tried creams, cleansers, vitamins and minerals. Is there any of these you would recommend?

Comment: This is not a site for diagnosis or diagnosis suggestions. There's Quora and other health forms for that.